# Why files aren't found with File.exist

Tags: ruby

I have a working directory like that one:

```
sascha@sascha-desktop:~/Musik/RMB/Youtube-Music$ ls -la
insgesamt 46456
drwxrwxr-x 2 sascha sascha     4096 Dez  9 10:32 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 sascha sascha     4096 Dez  6 22:47 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sascha sascha 20751305 Apr 22  2015 RMB - Spring-dJl7zWZYj-E.mp4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sascha sascha  6051641 Apr 22  2015 RMB - Spring.m4a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sascha sascha 20751305 Apr 22  2015 RMB - Spring.mp4
```

In my Ruby program i'm having two methods:

```
def self.rename(title)
    filename = title.to_s
    ext = file_exist_ogg_m4a(filename)
    filenamenew0 = filename.gsub(/ /, '_')
    pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s\_]/
    filenamenew = filenamenew0.split(//).keep_if do |chr|
      chr =~ pattern
    end.join
    puts 'Renaming the downloaded file'
    puts "Filename: #{filename}" # debug
    puts "Filenamenew: #{filenamenew}" # debug
    puts "Extension: #{ext}" # debug
    puts Dir.pwd # debug
    #FileUtils.mv("#{filename}.#{ext}", "#{filenamenew}.#{ext}")
    #[filenamenew, filename]
end

def self.file_exist_ogg_m4a(filename)
    puts 'Accessing file_exist_ogg_m4a'
    puts Dir.pwd # debug
    if File.exist?("#{filename}.ogg")
      ext = 'ogg'
    elsif File.exist?("#{filename}.m4a")
      ext = 'm4a'
    elsif File.exist?("#{filename}.webm")
      ext = 'webm'
    end
    puts ext # debug
    puts 'Closing file_exist_ogg_m4a'
    return ext # debug
  end
```

I'm getting the extension through the file_exist_ogg_m4a method.

By running the program it gives me:

```
Accessing file_exist_ogg_m4a
/home/sascha/Musik/RMB/Youtube-Music

Closing file_exist_ogg_m4a
Renaming the downloaded file
Filename: RMB - Spring
Filenamenew: RMB_-_Spring
Extension: 
/home/sascha/Musik/RMB/Youtube-Music
```

So it looks like i'm in the right directory, a #{filename}.m4a should be found, and the ext variable should contain "m4a".
But if i'm looking the running method "rename" looks me a empty #{ext}.

If i'm using that code it finds a m4a file:

```
dir = Dir.pwd
if !Dir.glob("#{dir}/*.ogg").empty?
  ext = 'ogg'
elsif !Dir.glob("#{dir}/*.m4a").empty?
  ext = 'm4a'
elsif !Dir.glob("#{dir}/*.webm").empty?
  ext = 'webm'
end
```

So i think it has to do with the string "filename".
Maybe anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

`File.exist?` is related to the current script directory, not to the internals of `Dir`. One might use:

```
File.exist?(File.join Dir.pwd, "#{filename}.ogg")
```

to achieve the requested functionality.